# RapidMiner: Access an Example of an ExampleSet by the Id-Attribute

Tags: java, groovy, attributes, identifier, rapidminer

I want to get an example from an id attribute. 
Actually this attribute was some regular attribute and i transformed it into an id attribute wiht the "SetRole" Operator now i want to get access on some examples in the "ExecuteScript" Operator. So my process is something like this: ExampleSet with some "text" regular Attribute -> transform it into a id Attribute with "SetRole" -> ScriptOperator
Now i wanted to use something like:

```
ExampleSet es = input[0];
es.remapIds();
Example e = es.getExampleFromId("Text");
```

but obviously getExampleFromId() only accepts double-value. But although the attribute type of "text" is "Polynomial", it seems like it contains something like strings. And the exampleSet after the SetRole Operator seems perfectly fine. So I wonder how i can access an Example from an id. (Casting doesnt work)
Help appreciated

EDIT: Okay, i get it now, the id there is not the value of the id-Attribute but just a intern identifier in the ExampleSet. But my question still remains how can i access a row of a ExampleSet by the id-Attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Filter Examples` operator can be used to filter examples where an attribute has a specific value. Perhaps the code for this could be useful as the basis for doing it in your own code.